# Windows Boot PreSessionInit time up to 50sec -struggling to find reason

Tags: windows, boot

I got new Dell XPS 9300 and out of the box boot time was around 45sec to see logon screen.
I started looking and it looks like I am not the only one who has a problem with this model and boot time. There is a separate forum thread where other Dell owners report the same issue.
Dell tried to replace hard disk and reinstalled Windows but that didn't make any difference. They are sending replacement laptop now but I think this might not be a solution in this case.

Looking at this forum I found suggestions to use "Windows Performance Toolkit" to diagnose slow boot.
I managed to find that my PreSMSS phase takes 32seconds

and the actuall delay is caused by this and takes 30sec
<pnpObject name="ACPI_HAL\PNP0C08\0" type="Device" activity="Start"startTime="103" endTime="30182" duration="30079" prePendTime="30079" description="Microsoft ACPI-Compliant System" friendlyName=""/>

I can't however narrow it down to what exactly is causing this delay.
etl link: https://we.tl/t-NLFYaIhOf8

Perhaps someone would be able to have a quick look and advise what it is as I am stuck with it.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't include links to external resources (other than images) in your question as the links may not be available in the future. [Edit] the question to make it self sufficient.

Comment: Adding an external link to the ETL file is perfectly valid.

Comment: Have _you_ performed a clean re-install of Windows yet? Preferably without third-party virus scanners etc.

Comment: yes I did. As I wrote, disk was replaced, Windows was reinstalled. Safe mode or any other mode doesn't make a difference. However if I use fast startup feature (which as we know is not really a cold boot) it only takes seconds to boot. That only points into direction that something is trying to load during PreSMSS phase and delays whole process.

Comment: The only thing I see that could be to blame is ACPI. The firmware (BIOS) may be erroneous. Look for an update. I can’t offer anything else. Dell is generally terrible as far as boot times are concerned.

Comment: thanks DanielB. I saw ACPI there too, just couldn't narrow it down to what exactly it is. Dell XPS laptops are usually very good actually. This is my 3rd generation. Two others would boot in 10-12sec from cold boot, maybe 15 with everything installed on them. BIOS has been updated to the latest. I tried to disable number of things in a BIOS too but no difference. I hoped someone here would be able to find out whats delaying start based on attached logs.